# how to bulkify soql with multiple where conditions

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 3 objects. `Child__c` is junction object, `ParentA__c` is master object, `Parentb__c` master object.

So `Child__c` (Many to Many relationship) is junction object between `ParentA__`c and `ParentB__c`. In `Child__c` i have 2 date fiels `Startdate`, `Enddate`.

while creating a junction object record need to maintain uniqueness using `ParentA__c`, `ParentB__c` and range of `Startdate` and `Enddate`.

example :  dd/mm/yyyy

```
Record1: startdate  10/06/2016  enddate 10/07/2016 save record sucessfully          
Record2: startdate  10/06/2016  enddate 02/07/2016 need to give error message 
Record1: startdate  20/06/2016  enddate 20/07/2017 save record sucessfully
Record2: startdate  20/06/2016  enddate 01/07/2016 need to give error message
```

For this i wrote below sample code. Please help me bulkify

```
trigger Jundupcheck on Child__c (before insert) {
    for (Child__c  ci : trigger.new) {
        // We only care if there is one record<br>      
        List<Child__c> resultList = [SELECT id,Name,Enddate__c,StartDate__c,(selected id) FROM Child__c WHERE ParentA__c = :ci.ParentA__c AND ParentB__c = :ci.ParentB__c and ((StartDate__c >= :ci.StartDate__c AND StartDate__c <= :ci.EndDate__c) OR (endDate__c >= :ci.StartDate__c AND endDate__c <= :ci.endDate__c))];
        // Raise the error back if any records found    
        if (resultList.size()>0) {
            ci.addError('Duplicate record, a Affisiation already exists for that combination');    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing is first, you will need to pull that SOQL statement out of the For Loop. So you'll want to collect the `ParentA__c` and `ParentB__c` and then do your SOQL.

```
Set<Id> aParents = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> bParents = new Set<Id>();

for(Child__c ci : trigger.new) {
    aParents.add(ci.ParentA__c);
    bParents.add(ci.ParentB__c);

}

List<Child__c> resultList = [SELECT Id, Name, Enddate__c, StartDate__c FROM Child__c WHERE ParentA__c IN :aParents ANd ParentB__c IN :bParents];
```

I'm still not entirely clear on how the dates make a record unique, but you'll have to do the processing for those after you make the SOQL query.

**Note:** In the case where you have more than 1 child object being inserted it is possible that the `resultList` will have records with either ParentA__c or ParentB__c not matching your Child__c record so you will have to double check those as well.